# Flutter - Validate a phone number using Regex

Tags: android, ios, regex, dart, flutter

In my Flutter mobile app, I am trying to validate a phone number using `regex`. Below are the conditions.

1. Phone numbers must contain 10 digits.
2. In case country code us used, it can be 12 digits.  (example country codes: +12, 012)
3. No space or no characters allowed between digits

In simple terms, here is are the only "valid" phone numbers

`0776233475`, `+94776233475`, `094776233475`

Below is what I tried, but it do not work.

```
String _phoneNumberValidator(String value) {
    Pattern pattern =
        r'/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
      return 'Enter Valid Phone Number';
    else
      return null;
  }
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could make the first part optional matching either a `+` or 0 followed by a 9. Then match 10 digits:

```
^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[+0]9)?` Optionally match a `+` or `0` followed by 9
- `[0-9]{10}` Match 10 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mhXP2g/2)

Answer (score 56):

Validation using Regex:

```
String validateMobile(String value) {
    String pattern = r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10,12}$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (value.length == 0) {
          return 'Please enter mobile number';
    }
    else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Please enter valid mobile number';
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  @override
  String validator(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Mobile can\'t be empty';
    } else if (value.isNotEmpty) {
      //bool mobileValid = RegExp(r"^(?:\+88||01)?(?:\d{10}|\d{13})$").hasMatch(value);

      bool mobileValid =
          RegExp(r'^(?:\+?88|0088)?01[13-9]\d{8}$').hasMatch(value);
      return mobileValid ? null : "Invalid mobile";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the `RegExp` provided by [@Dharmesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56488868/6618622)

This is how you can do it with null safety.

```dart
bool isPhoneNoValid(String? phoneNo) {
  if (phoneNo == null) return false;
  final regExp = RegExp(r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10,12}$)');
  return regExp.hasMatch(phoneNo);
}
```

Usage:

```dart
bool isValid = isPhoneNoValid('your_phone_no');
```

Comment: What should I do if I don't want a country code like (+91) in RegEx. I just want to validate a normal 10 digit phone number.

Comment: @JayTillu I'm sorry as `RegEx` isn't my cup of tea.

Answer (score 0):

```
String phoneNumberValidator(String value) {
    Pattern pattern =
        r'\+994\s+\([0-9]{2}\)\s+[0-9]{3}\s+[0-9]{2}\s+[0-9]{2}';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
      return 'Enter Valid Phone Number';
    else
      return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer contains verified phone numbers for the Republic of Egypt

```js
 static bool isPhoneNumberValid(String phoneNumber) {
    return RegExp(r'^(010|011|012|015)[0-9]{8}$').hasMatch(phoneNumber);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?