# How to check entered phone number is valid or not with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to check to entered phone number is valid or not .
means, if I enter the wrong number which does not exist in the world, so it shows me a toast with content "Please enter a valid number"

```
 Expanded(
   child: TextField(
     keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
       border: InputBorder.none, 
       hintText: "Phone Number", 
     ),
     onChanged: (value){
      setState(() {
        phoneValue=value; 
      });
     //String telNo = value==null?("+91" + value) :null;
     print("phoneNumbe:$phoneNo");
     this.phoneNo = isCountryCodeSelected ? "+" + countryCode + value : "+91" + value ;
     print("phoneNo="+phoneNo);
    },
   ),
 )
```

Comment: Have you tried [TextFieldForm](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation)?

Comment: yes, but I don't need validator, because I already validated . just want to check entered phone number is exist or not?

Comment: @ShrutiRamnandanSharma For that you need to call that number

Comment: I think you should explain what's "valid number"? In frontend, we use regex as Samcom's answer. In backend, we have no idea what number is existed or not, but call the api, or If you are ISP, you could know If It's existed in the world.

Comment: @ShrutiRamnandanSharma found any soln yet?

Comment: @NimishBansal yes , You can look at my answer, which I recently added. I guess this is correct.

Comment: Use Regex: MOBILE_REGEX = "[6-9][0-9]{9}"; to validate no in india

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think,
The solution was in my code and
I was so dumb ,couldn't recognised it.

please look at the comments in the code.

```
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieval=(String verId){
      this.verificationId=verId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent=(String verId, [int forceCodeResend]){
      this.verificationId=verId;    
      smsCodeDialog(context).then((value){        
      }).catchError((onError){
         print(onError);    
      });
    };


//This will verified you number

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted = (AuthCredential credential) {
     print("verified");
    };

// and if your number doesn't exist or doesn't match with your country code,Then this will show you an error message

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verfifailed=(AuthException exception){
      print("${exception.message}");
       Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "The number is invalid", backgroundColor: Colors.red); 
       //Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "${exception.message}"); //
    };

    if(phoneNo !=null){
      await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: this.phoneNo,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieval,
        codeSent: smsCodeSent,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verfifailed
      );
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 23):

please check this doc https://medium.com/@nitishk72/form-validation-in-flutter-d762fbc9212c

code snippet TextFormField validator

```
Widget FormUI() {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          validator: validateName,
          onSaved: (String val) {
            _name = val;
          },
        ),
        new TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Mobile'),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
          validator: validateMobile,
          onSaved: (String val) {
            _mobile = val;
          },
        ),
        new TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          validator: validateEmail,
          onSaved: (String val) {
            _email = val;
          },
        ),
        new SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _validateInputs,
          child: new Text('Validate'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  String validateName(String value) {
    if (value.length < 3)
      return 'Name must be more than 2 charater';
    else
      return null;
  }

  String validateMobile(String value) {
// Indian Mobile number are of 10 digit only
    if (value.length != 10)
      return 'Mobile Number must be of 10 digit';
    else
      return null;
  }

  String validateEmail(String value) {
    Pattern pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
      return 'Enter Valid Email';
    else
      return null;
  }
```

validate phone number [Flutter - Validate a phone number using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552230/flutter-validate-a-phone-number-using-regex)

```
String validateMobile(String value) {
String patttern = r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10,12}$)';
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
if (value.length == 0) {
      return 'Please enter mobile number';
}
else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Please enter valid mobile number';
}
return null;
}
```

With package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder
Support build-in and custom validator

```
FormBuilderTextField(
            attribute: "age",
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Age"),
            validators: [
              FormBuilderValidators.numeric(),
              FormBuilderValidators.max(70),
            ],
          ),

FormBuilderTextField(
attribute: "over_18",
decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Are you over 18?"),
validators: [
    FormBuilderValidators.required(),
    (val){
        if(val.toLowerCase() != "yes")
            return "The answer must be Yes";
    },
],
),
```

You can put your own phone number validate logic in validators

Answer (score 13):

```dart
/// regex ref: https://ihateregex.io/expr/phone/
bool isValidPhoneNumber(String? value) =>
    RegExp(r'(^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$)').hasMatch(value ?? '');
```

explanation
[image: phone regex]

Comment: This regex works well for international phone numbers!

Answer (score 11):

```
- You could make the first part optional matching either a + or 0 followed by a 9. 
- Then match 10 digits:

- ^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10}$
- ^ Start of string
- (?:[+0]9)? Optionally match a + or 0 followed by 9
- [0-9]{10} Match 10 digits
- $ End of string

//Here is an Example

String validateMobile(String value) {
String patttern = r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10,12}$)';
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
if (value.length == 0) {
      return 'Please enter mobile number';
}
else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Please enter valid mobile number';
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: thank you but this solution can't resolve my problem. Could you please Re-read my post?

Answer (score 2):

using [this](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber) for country based phone number format check.

Comment: Does not support Dart at the time of writing